# Home page MegaMenu "View All Products" issue

Tags: magento2

On my home page, in the mega menu, there is a new drop down added by our free lance developer, who has left he project. So when I click on that "view all products" option it takes me to the old link. From where can I change the link. Please help

Website : Kiabzanew.site

Screenshot:

[image: HomePage]

Navigation.phmtl code

```
<?php $helperGenerator = $this->helper('MGS\Mmegamenu\Helper\Generator') ?>
<?php $html = $helperGenerator->getMenuCacheHtml(1); ?>

<?php echo $helperGenerator->filter($html); ?>
```

Generator.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MGS\Mmegamenu\Helper;

class Generator extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory
     */
    protected $_blockFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $_resource;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_date;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context        $context      
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface   $storeManager 
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider  
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection    $resource     
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime  $date         
     * @param \Ves\Megamenu\Helper\Data                    $helper       
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_filterProvider  = $filterProvider;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->_resource     = $resource;
        $this->_date         = $date;
    }

    public function getMenuCacheHtml($menuId, $typeMenu = NULL) {
        //if (!$this->helper->getConfig('general_settings/enable_cache')) return false;
        $resource   = $this->_resource;
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $store      = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $storeId    = $store->getId();
        $table      = $resource->getTableName('mgs_megamenu_cache');
        $select     = $connection->select()->from($table)->where('parent_id = ?', $menuId)->where('store_id = ?', $storeId);
        $row        = $connection->fetchRow($select);

        if (empty($row)) {
            if($menuId == 1){
                $html = $this->generateMenuHtml($menuId);
            }else{
                if($typeMenu == 'horizontal'){
                    $html = $this->generateHorizontalMenuHtml($menuId);
                }else {
                    $html = $this->generateVerticalMenuHtml($menuId);
                }
            }
            $data['parent_id']       = $menuId;
            $data['store_id']      = $storeId;
            $data['html']          = $html;
            $data['creation_time'] = $this->_date->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $connection->insert($table, $data);
        } else {
            $timestamp   = strtotime($row['creation_time']);
            $menuDay     = date("d", $timestamp);
            $currentDate = $this->_date->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $currentDay  = date("d", strtotime($currentDate));
            if ($currentDay == $menuDay) {
                $html = $row['html'];
            } else {
                if($menuId == 1){
                    $html = $this->generateMenuHtml($menuId);
                }else{
                    if($typeMenu == 'horizontal'){
                        $html = $this->generateHorizontalMenuHtml($menuId);
                    }else {
                        $html = $this->generateVerticalMenuHtml($menuId);
                    }
                }
                $connection->update($table, ['html' => $html, 'creation_time' => $currentDate], ['parent_id = ?' => $menuId, 'store_id = ?' => $storeId]);
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }

    protected function generateMenuHtml($menuId) {
        $html = $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('MGS\Mmegamenu\Block\Mmegamenu')->setMenuId($menuId)->setTemplate("MGS_Mmegamenu::cache/top_menu.phtml")->toHtml();
        return $html;
    }

    protected function generateHorizontalMenuHtml($menuId) {
        $html = $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('MGS\Mmegamenu\Block\Horizontal')->setMenuId($menuId)->setTemplate("MGS_Mmegamenu::cache/horizontal_menu.phtml")->toHtml();
        return $html;
    }

    protected function generateVerticalMenuHtml($menuId) {
        $html = $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('MGS\Mmegamenu\Block\Vertical')->setMenuId($menuId)->setTemplate("MGS_Mmegamenu::cache/vertical_menu.phtml")->toHtml();
        return $html;
    }

    public function filter($str)
    {
        $filter = $this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter();
        $html   = $filter->filter($str);
        return $html;
    }
}
```

TopMenu.phtml code

```
<?php $megaMenu = $this->getMegamenuItems(); ?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('MGS\Mmegamenu\Helper\Data') ?>
<?php $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>      
<?php $logo = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo'); ?>

<?php if((count($megaMenu)>0) || $helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/home')):?>
    <?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/homeposition') == "" || $helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/homeposition') == 0): ?>
        <?php $positionHomeLink = 0; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $positionHomeLink = $helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/homeposition'); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul id="mainMenu" class="nav nav-main nav-main-menu">
            <?php if(count($megaMenu)>0): ?>

                <?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/home')): ?>
                    <?php if($positionHomeLink <= 0): ?>
                        <li class="mega-menu-item megamenu-homelink<?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/homelogo')): ?> logo-item<?php endif ?><?php if($this->isHomePage()): ?> active<?php endif ?>">
                            <?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/homelogo')): ?>
                                <?php if(!$this->isHomePage()): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>" class="level0">
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <strong class="logo">
                                <?php endif ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $logo->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo->getLogoAlt() ?>" width="<?php echo $logo->getLogoWidth() ?>" height="<?php echo $logo->getLogoHeight() ?>">
                                <?php if(!$this->isHomePage()): ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    </strong>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>" class="level0">
                                    <?php echo $helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/hometext') ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php $i=0; foreach($megaMenu as $item): $i++ ?>
                            <li class="<?php echo $this->getClass($item) ?>">
                                <?php echo $this->getMenuHtml($item) ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php foreach($megaMenu as $item): ?>
                            <?php if($item->getPosition() < $positionHomeLink): ?>
                                <li class="<?php echo $this->getClass($item) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $this->getMenuHtml($item) ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?> 

                        <li class="mega-menu-item megamenu-homelink<?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/homelogo')): ?> logo-item<?php endif ?><?php if($this->isHomePage()): ?> active<?php endif ?>">
                            <?php if($helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/homelogo')): ?>
                                <?php if(!$this->isHomePage()): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>" class="level0">
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <strong class="logo">
                                <?php endif ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $logo->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo->getLogoAlt() ?>" width="<?php echo $logo->getLogoWidth() ?>" height="<?php echo $logo->getLogoHeight() ?>">
                                <?php if(!$this->isHomePage()): ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    </strong>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>" class="level0">
                                    <?php echo $helper->getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/hometext') ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </li>

                        <?php foreach($megaMenu as $item): ?>
                            <?php if($item->getPosition() >= $positionHomeLink): ?>
                                <li class="<?php echo $this->getClass($item) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $this->getMenuHtml($item) ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php $i=0; foreach($megaMenu as $item): $i++ ?>
                        <li class="<?php echo $this->getClass($item) ?>">
                            <?php echo $this->getMenuHtml($item) ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Please post navigation.phtml file code to debug.

Comment: You can search **devnew.kiabza.com** in database and update with **kiabzanew.site**, if you see in database.

Comment: @Ranganathan done posting the code.

Comment: @ Ashok Sure i will check, any specific file ? or just core_config ?

Comment: Check `MGS\Mmegamenu\Helper\Generator` file...You can find the url mapping...Or post helper file code also.

Comment: @Patrik Please check in the whole database and if not find anywhere in database then search in whole project files.

Comment: @Ranganathan posted the code, pls check

Comment: @Ashok sure i will do that.

Comment: @Ashok I checked the entire DB no such link, searching whole project file would be to hard.

Comment: I checked your file, the link must be in `MGS_Mmegamenu::cache/top_menu.phtml`...If you want exact folder path let me know.

Comment: @Ranganathan I searched for the file name top_menu.phtml and found 3 in the entire directory. None of them had the link.

Comment: Please update the file from `app/design/frontend/YOURVENDOR/YOURTHEME/MGS_Mmegamenu/templates/cache/top_menu.phtml` if not found then update file from `app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/view/frontend/templates/cache/top_menu.phtml`

Comment: @Ranganathan Updated the code. Thanks

Comment: @Patrik - If you are able to search the word in a specific directory of your project then please search **devnew.kiabza.com** in `app/design/frontend/YOURVENDOR/YOURTHEME/` and `app/code/` - I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: @patrik, Have you cleared MGS MegaMenu cache from admin?